# List Model not geting posted to api through ajax call?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

Hi all i build a json object in jquery and trying to post it to my api but the data is not posted there can any one help me with the issue here

```
this is my json object

   {"Employee":[{"EmployeeCode":"1","EmployeeName":"Sudheer","EmployeeId":"1"}]}
```

My Model

```
 public class Employee
  {
    public long   EmployeeId{ get; set; }
    public long   EmployeeCode{ get; set; }        
    public string EmployeeName{ get; set; }      
  }
```

my api method

```
    [ActionName("InsertOrUpdateEmployee")]
     public void InsertOrUpdateEmployee(List<Employee> Employee)
    {
        new repo.InsertOrUpdateEmployee(Employee);
    }
```

JavaScript code to call API

```
   PreReqisites.Employee=[];//in this i push my employee details
   var employees= JSON.stringify(PreReqisites.Employee);
   var employeedata= '{"Employee":' + jsdCustomers + '}';
   var varemployee= jQuery.parseJSON(employeedata);
    console.log(varemployee);
   alert(varemployee);
   alert(JSON.stringify(varemployee));
  $.post("api/Employee/InsertOrUpdateEmployee", {   Employee: varemployee}, function (data) {
    alert("success");
    });
```

when put a breakpoint and check it i have count zero in my employee,the data is not geting posted there can any one help me with this

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right code?

Comment: @Musa had made changes  in my code there where some errors befor

Answer (score 0):

[HTTPPost] is not working, I am troubleshooting it , but you can do the same data post with [HTTPGet] it is working as expected.

**Javascript code to post data**

```
var postData = { "Employee": [{ "EmployeeCode": "1", "EmployeeName": "Sudheer", "EmployeeId": "1"}] };
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "api/Employee/EmployeeController",
    data: postData,
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        //alert(data.Result);
    }
});
```

**Controller action method**

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public void InsertOrUpdateEmployee([FromUri]IList<Employee> Employee)
    {

    }
}
```

**Screenshot of debug view to show the proof**

[image]